# Is it possible to handle User Defined Exception using JAX WS Dispatch API?

Tags: java, exception, jaxb, jax-ws, jbossws

I'm performing dynamic webservices call using following code snippet:

```
    JAXBContext jc = getJAXBContext(requestClass, responseClass, jaxbContextExtraClasses);
    Dispatch<Object> dispatch = service.createDispatch(portQName, jc, Service.Mode.PAYLOAD);

    Object requestValue = getRequestValue(requestClass, pOrderedParameters);
    JAXBElement<?> request =
            new JAXBElement(new QName(serviceQNameStr, pOperationName), requestValue.getClass(), null, requestValue);
    Object tmpResponse = dispatch.invoke(request);
```

Invocation works perfectly, except if I add a user defined exception on the service (a basic UserException extends java.lang.Exception).

First I get:

> javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException:
>   unexpected element
>   (uri:"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/",
>   local:"Fault"). Expected elements are
>   <{http://my.namespace/}myMethod>,<{http://my.namespace/}myResponse>

Then I added the UserException_Exception JAX-WS generated type to my JAXB Context, and then get:

> Caused by: com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException: 1 counts of IllegalAnnotationExceptions
>   java.lang.StackTraceElement does not have a no-arg default constructor.
>    this problem is related to the following location:
>     at java.lang.StackTraceElement
>     at public java.lang.StackTraceElement[] java.lang.Throwable.getStackTrace()
>     at java.lang.Throwable
>     at java.lang.Exception

Only solution available I found are:

- dispatch directly a Soap message and handle Soap fault directly (this is the way Jboss JAX-WS implementation performs a standard JAX-WS call using services interfaces). This is not an available solution for me, I want to use a high level implementation (the more I get close to Soap message the less dynamic my code can be)
- usage of JAXBRIContext.ANNOTATION_READER, which is implementation specific and not an available solution for me, in order to annotate annotates java.lang.Exception as @XmlTransient

The service with a user defined exception performs well using the JAX-WS generated standard client stubs and using a tool such Soap UI. Problem occurs in deserialization of the message when I have no user defined exception artifact in the JAXB context, and during invocation when I add those non JAXB compatible artifacts in the JAXB context.

I'm usign Jboss WS webservice stack within Jboss 4.2.3.GA

Any elegant solution to this problem is welcomed !

Answer (score 0):

Have you modified your WSDL accordingly when you added exception, or is WSDL generated from your SEI? Is there a Fault element for your Exception defined there?

Comment: Thank you for your answer, the WSDL is generated from my SEI, and there is a Fault element for the Exception in the operation:
      <fault name="ActionIdNotFoundExceptionDto">
        <soap:fault name="ActionIdNotFoundExceptionDto" use="literal"/>
      </fault>
If I perform the call using a JAX-WS generated stub, an ActionIdNotFoundExceptionDto_Exception is thrown, containing a ActionIdNotFoundExceptionDto bean. That is the behavior I expected using dispatch method.